# GetThreadContext Fails - GetLastError returns 998

Tags: c#, .net

So I'm having an issue with GetThreadContext. I am able to create the process suspended, but it fails when trying to GetThreadContext. It returns the error code "998" when calling GetLastError. It only fails on X64, not on X86.

Line:

```
IntPtr[] pInfo = new IntPtr[4];
uint[] ctxt = new uint[0xb3];
ctxt[0] = 0x10002;
if (GetThreadContext(pInfo[1], ctxt))
{
    //Other stuff done here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the process that you created a 32 bit process?  If so on 64 bit Windows you'll need to call [Wow64GetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get it's context.

From the [GetThreadContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> A 64-bit application can retrieve the context of a WOW64 thread using
>   the Wow64GetThreadContext function.

You could also mark you .NET application as x86 so it runs as a 32 bit process on 64 bit Windows.